# Two-Dimensional Array Searching Algorithm Optimisation

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, search, optimization

I have been given a "Sand box" of variable length and width. I've been given instructions to find a "shovel" of static size, which may be oriented either horizontally or vertically. I implement the following algorithm in order to search the least amount of times to find **one** valid location (one which corresponds to a "part of the object") in the grid:

```
found = false;
nShift = 0;
shovelSize = 4;
for(int i = 0; i < SandBoxRows; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < SandBoxColumns; j+=shovelSize) {
        found = probeSandBoxTwo(('A' + i), (j + 1 + nShift));
    }

    if(nShift >= shovelSize - 1 || nShift > SandBoxColumns) {
        nShift = 0;
    } else {
        nShift++;
    }
}
```

In this case, the "Sand box" will be tested by the function as described below.

[image: Function description]

I completely recreate this scenario with a "Sand box" whose size is fixed (though easily manipulated) whose shovel is still randomly placed and oriented within the following code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int ROW = 12;
const int COL = 16;
char sandbox[ROW][COL];

bool probeSandBoxTwo(char c, int i);
void displayResults(int sCount, bool found, int x, int y);
void displaySandbox();
void displaySearchPattern();
void fillSandbox();
void placeShovel();

int main() {
    fillSandbox();
    placeShovel();
    displaySandbox();

    //define your variables here
    bool found;
    int nShift,
        sCount,
        shovelSize,
        x,
        y;


    found = false;
    nShift = 0;
    shovelSize = 4;
    sCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < ROW && !found; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < COL && !found; j+=shovelSize) {
            found = probeSandBoxTwo(('A' + i), (j + 1 + nShift));
            x = i;
            y = j + nShift;
            sCount++;
            cout << "Search conducted at (" << i << ", " << (j + nShift) << ")" << endl;
        }

        if(nShift >= shovelSize - 1 || nShift > ROW) {
            nShift = 0;
        } else {
            nShift++;
        }
    }
    displayResults(sCount, found, x, y);
    displaySearchPattern();
}

bool probeSandBoxTwo(char c, int i) {
    if(sandbox[c-'A'][i-1] == 'X') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

void displayResults(int sCount, bool found, int x, int y) {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Total searches: " << sCount << endl;
    cout << endl;
    if(found) {
        cout << "Shovel found at coordinates: (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
    }
}

void displaySandbox() {
    cout << "  ";
    for(int i = 0; i < COL; i++) {
        cout << (i % 10); //show index numbers [col]
    }
    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        cout << (i % 10) << " "; //show index numbers [row]
        for(int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            cout << sandbox[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void displaySearchPattern() {
    int nShift = 0;
    int shovelSize = 4;

    cout << endl << "  ";
    for(int i = 0; i < COL; i++) {
        cout << (i % 10); //show index numbers [col]
    }
    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        cout << (i % 10) << " "; //show index numbers [row]
        for(int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            if(!((j + nShift) % shovelSize)) {
                cout << 'o';
            } else {
                cout << '.';
            }
        }

        if(nShift >= shovelSize - 1 || nShift > COL) {
            nShift = 0;
        } else {
            nShift++;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void fillSandbox() {
    for(int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            sandbox[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
}

void placeShovel() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int shovelRow,
        shovelCol,
        shovelSize = 4;
    if(rand() % 2) {
        //horizontal
        shovelRow = rand() % ROW + 1;
        shovelCol = rand() % (COL - (shovelSize - 1)) + 1;
        for(int i = shovelCol - 1; i < shovelSize + (shovelCol - 1); i++) {
            sandbox[shovelRow - 1][i] = 'X';
        }
    } else {
        //vertical
        shovelRow = rand() % (ROW - (shovelSize - 1)) + 1;
        shovelCol = rand() % COL + 1;
        for(int i = shovelRow - 1; i < shovelSize + (shovelRow - 1); i++) {
            sandbox[i][shovelCol - 1] = 'X';
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, I also graphically display the pattern (when run) with which my algorithm searches.

Is this truly the optimal search pattern for such a scenario, is my implementation correct, and if so, why might I be having incorrect results returned?

A given test driver reports the following results:

[image: Results]

The [source code](http://pastebin.com/VEBdb7CH) for this result (and its [test driver](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=07152681994269636895)).

Comment: You should only seed rand once.

Comment: @NeilKirk Noted. What about my algorithm?

Comment: what about diagonal search ? with horizontal and vertical probing you need to cover whole area twice, if you search diagonally then you need it to do just once (I think with less probes). Also the shovel is just a 1 cell wide line? if not then you can diagonally probing every wide-1 cell ...

Comment: I don't know what the optimal pattern is, but I bet you could find it by using an integer program solver to solve the problem of covering all shovel positions with the minimum number of probes.

Comment: @Spektre My program is pretty detailed about the scenario, and if you bothered to run my test program you would see precisely the searching pattern that I used (which is a diagonal searching pattern).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat That's not the objective. Did you read my post?

Comment: I did, in fact, read your post, including the part where it says "is this truly the optimal search pattern for such a scenario".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    found = false;
    nShift = 0;
    shovelSize = 4;
    for(int i = 0; i < SandBoxRows; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; (j + nShift) < SandBoxColumns; j+=shovelSize) {
            found = probeSandBoxTwo(('A' + i), (j + 1 + nShift));
        }

        if(nShift >= shovelSize - 1 || nShift > SandBoxColumns) {
            nShift = 0;
        } else {
            nShift++;
        }
    }
```

This corrects an error in the conditional portion of the for loop header which did not account for the index-shifting variable `nShift`.